# NODEJS - Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, http, events, callback, header

I have function, that executes when 'dataCompiled' event fires, it looks like his:

```
eventEmitter.on('dataCompiled', function () {
        json = JSON.stringify({
          conversations: convs
        });
        res.json(json).end();
        return;
      });
```

But when i refreshing page, i getting error

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out, need send json directly to end function, so it'll look like that:

```
res.end(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to stringify and end a call to res.json if I'm not mistaken:

```
eventEmitter.on('dataCompiled', function () {
    return res.json({
        conversations: convs
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not sending more data after this call? You shouldn't have to use `res.end()`: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.end .

If there is another place in your code you're sending more data to res it will give the error message you are receiving, res.end is not fixing the underlying problem.

Comment: No, this is the only place where i call **res**